# Sqoop incremantal import fails for Teradata

Tags: import, teradata, sqoop

My platform: CDH 5.10 Quickstart VM and Teradata TDEXPRESS 16 VM version.
I am using Sqoop and the Teradata JDBC driver- 
tdgssconfig.jar, teradata-connector-1.5.3.jar,terajdbc4.jar 
My sqoop job is failing with the following errors.

Any suggestions?

```
[cloudera@quickstart sqoop]$ sqoop job --create incjobtd1 -- import --connect jdbc:teradata://192.168.142.129/DATABASE=teradb  --driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver  --username dbc --password dbc   --table ACCT   --incremental lastmodified
       --check-column  ECF_XTRC_TS        --target-dir /user/cloudera/teradb/acct2 -m 1 --as-parquetfile  --append
    Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
    Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
    17/08/09 01:44:49 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.10.0
    17/08/09 01:44:54 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
    [cloudera@quickstart sqoop]$ sqoop job --exec incjobtd1
    Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
    Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
    17/08/09 01:45:14 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.10.0
    Enter password:
    17/08/09 01:45:25 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
    17/08/09 01:45:25 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
    17/08/09 01:45:25 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
    17/08/09 01:45:25 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Will generate java class as codegen_ACCT
    17/08/09 01:45:32 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM ACCT AS t WHERE 1=0
    17/08/09 01:45:32 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM ACCT AS t WHERE 1=0
    17/08/09 01:45:32 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
    Note: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/fc68a3f34abd80bde713cf1709dbc330/codegen_ACCT.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    17/08/09 01:45:54 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/fc68a3f34abd80bde713cf1709dbc330/codegen_ACCT.jar
    17/08/09 01:46:06 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM ACCT AS t WHERE 1=0
    17/08/09 01:46:07 ERROR manager.SqlManager: SQL exception accessing current timestamp: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.00.00.23] [Error 3706] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error: expected something between '(' and ')'.
    java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.00.00.23] [Error 3706] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error: expected something between '(' and ')'.
            at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDatabaseSQLException(ErrorFactory.java:309)
            at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.ReceiveInitSubState.action(ReceiveInitSubState.java:103)
            at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.subStateMachine(StatementReceiveState.java:311)
            at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.action(StatementReceiveState.java:200)
            at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.runBody(StatementController.java:137)
            at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.run(StatementController.java:128)
            at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:389)
            at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:331)
            at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.doNonPrepExecuteQuery(TDStatement.java:319)
            at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeQuery(TDStatement.java:1121)
            at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getCurrentDbTimestamp(SqlManager.java:987)
            at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.initIncrementalConstraints(ImportTool.java:328)
            at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:498)
            at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:615)
            at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.execJob(JobTool.java:213)
            at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.run(JobTool.java:268)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
    17/08/09 01:46:07 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Could not get current time from database
            at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.initIncrementalConstraints(ImportTool.java:330)
            at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:498)
            at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:615)
            at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.execJob(JobTool.java:213)
            at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.run(JobTool.java:268)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)

    [cloudera@quickstart sqoop]$
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `--append` and `lastmodified` modified together. This is not correct. Please find below detailed difference between them.

Sqoop supports two types of incremental imports: append and `lastmodified`. You can use the --incremental argument to specify the type of incremental import to perform.

You should specify `append` mode when importing a table where new rows are continually being added with increasing row id values. You specify the column containing the row’s id with `--check-column`. Sqoop imports rows where the check column has a value greater than the one specified with `--last-value`.

An alternate table update strategy supported by Sqoop is called `lastmodified` mode. You should use this when rows of the source table may be updated, and each such update will set the value of a last-modified column to the current timestamp.

So suppose your table have some new insert and sone net update as well, your Sqoop job will be.

`sqoop job --create incjobtd1 -- import --connect jdbc:teradata://192.168.142.129/DATABASE=teradb  \
--driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver  --username dbc --password dbc \
--table ACCT   --incremental lastmodified --check-column  ECF_XTRC_TS \
--target-dir /user/cloudera/teradb/acct2 -m 1 --as-parquetfile`

Comment: It is a bug. The Same identical statement was tested for MySQL without error.